# multithreaded implementation for ProcessBuilder design feedback

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a fairly new Java developer, so I'm looking for some community feedback on how they would implement a solution to the problem I need to solve, and feedback on my proposed solution.

Without going into too much detail, here's the desire:

1. I have the need process a lot of data then perform 7 steps on this data in a very generic manner.  I already have an application/framework that does this extremely efficiently, and in a restartable and safe and most importantly, isolated, manner.  It's important I leverage this existing framework.
2. I need to do this with MANY different instances of data, and in a fairly short time period.  I would perform this in a serial manner via the above framework if I had the time to do so, but I won't.  I need to be building/splitting/checksumming some data, while zipping and transmitting other data or it will never finish in time.

My thought is to leverage my existing application/framework (we'll call this the "child" ) within a separate application, using a queue of ProcessBuilder() calls in a separate application, the ("parent").  This solution allows me to leverage existing restartable frameworks for both the parent and child applications.

Is this an approach that would be looked down on?  Is it a reliable approach?  Even if you don't like the approach, if you determined looping through tasks using ProcessBuilder was the best option, how would you solve it?

Pseudo code would be something similar to the following (fortunately actual code isn't too much longer)

```
Class Task {
    //contains all the information for the task we need to complete
    String taskArgs;
}

Class TaskWatcher implements Runnable {
    //constructor requires process object for Constructor
    //boolean isFinished();
    process.waitfor();
    isFinished=true;
}

Class TaskOutStream implements Runnable {
    //constructor requires process object & TaskWatcher object
    //Receives and redirects output of process
}

Class Semaphore {
    //constructor sets int threadCount (We'll call it "3" for now)
    synchronized acquireThread{
    while threadCount==0, wait();
        threadcount--
    }
    synchronized releaseThread{
        threadcount++
        notify(); 
    }
}
Class TaskThread implements Runnable (
    // constructor requires Task Object
    run() {
        semaphoreObject.acquireThread();
        Process p = ProcessBuilder.command("cmd text", "args").start();
        tw = TaskWatcher(p);
        ThreadOutStream(p, tw);
    }
}

Class TaskRunner {
    //Constructor requires ArrayList<Task> 
    //For each Task t
    TaskThread thread = new TaskThread(t);
    thread.start();
}
```

Assuming that all the "return;"s from the threads are present, and restart functionality is handled externally from the queue of work (parent) or the actual work (child) level, does this approach make sense? Is it destined for failure?

Still haven't been able to find a really good reason for not doing this, anyone?

Comment: The one thing to jumps out at me is that you should probably be using seperate threads for both the error and outputstreams (personally).  The one reason (me for) is that it's possible that the standard output stream may block with no output while the error stream is filling up...IMHO

Comment: Do you have this same concern if I leverage ProcessBuilder option of redirecting standard error into standard out?

Comment: No, that would probably work nicely ;)

Comment: Sweet.  unrelated but...this is my first night on stack, and I'm trolling other threads to see if I can answer some sybase related questions and I can't seem to find the ability to add the first comment on a question.  I can "answer" a question, or follow-up a comment with another comment...but I can't be the first one to comment (like you did here)

Comment: You need to build some reputation before you can add comments (and do other stuff), so basically, you need to leave an answer.  If people like it (or accept it), this will build you reputation and you will gradually be grant new "privileges"